# Make certain test silent in Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, console, jestjs, silent

Is there any way to make a certain test silent (show console output only if it fails) in Jest? Looks like `jest --silent` makes all tests silent, which is not desirable. I need to simulate an error and make sure it's correctly handled, but unfortunately there is a third-party code that calls console.error in this case. But I don't want disable console.error completely, since I need to see the details if it fails.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to mute individual tests? I have one test that generates a LOT of output and would very much like to silence it (but only when successful).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to silence a test case *directly*, but you could always use a different `testRegex` with a different jest configuration for your test files.

For example, you could adopt the following naming convention for your test files:

- `myfile.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`: Jest should not suppress any output (console.log, errors, etc)
- `myfile.silent.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`: Jest should suppress the output

and, in your `package.json`, define your test scripts this way:

```
"test": "yarn test:default && yarn test:silent",
"test:silent": "jest __tests__\\/.*\\(silent\\)\\.\\(jsx?\\|tsx?\\)$ --silent",
"test:default": "jest __tests__\\/\\(?!.*silent\\).*\\.\\(jsx?\\|tsx?\\)$",
```

It's not easy to read regexes in the `package.json`, so I made this:

https://regex101.com/r/cFX9FW/1